VS 2022 Community installation absolutely stops my computer
My OS : Windows 11 , build 26257 (Insider Preview Canary), x64
CPU : Ryzen 7 2700 8 core
RAM : DDR 4 , 3200, 32 Gb
Graphic card 1 : Nvidia GTX 1660 , 6Gb
Graphic card 2 : Nvidia GT 710
Mother board : ASRock B450M Pro
Disks ; 1: PCI SSD , 2: SATA SSD, 3:SATA IDE
Connected to : Samsung monitor, Lg monitor, Mic, Bluetooth, Webcam, keyboard , mouse,       internet.
When Setup of VS finishing work and it try run VS I have immediately black screen, any messages ( the same I had when I tried install NET. framework 8 . or any other ) .Only one thing I can do is just turn computer off ) .
Thanks  for Your help . Problem for me is serious because I can't work on my projects.

I uninstalled all versions of VS I only had.
I uninstalled all versions of NET. frame works I only had
Using software as well as manually, I removed all the remnants, like Folders,   files, etc.
I did all like above with registry.
I had disconnect absoluty all except keyboard, mouse, monitors, disks and Graphic cards
I removed all content from autostart and from services ( all possible )
I restarted my computer
I downloaded fresh version from VS download page.
I started fresh installation

Result : When Setup of VS finishing work and it try run VS I have immediately black screen, any messages ( the same I had when I tried install NET. framework 8 . or any other ) .Only one thing I can do is just turn computer off ) .

Perhaps you can try to obtain relevant logs to analyze the cause of the problem. Open the Developer Command Prompt for VS 2022 and enter the command: devenv /log "\Path_to_store_logs\xxx.xml"
After opening VS here, reproduce the problem, and finally close VS, which will generate the log. You can also try to check whether there are any related warning or error messages recorded in the Event Viewer.

For Visual Studio setup issues, here are suggestions you can try to troubleshoot your issue.
1.Since black screen occurs when installing VS  or NET. framework 8, it seems something is incompatible or missing with your Operating system. Please ensure that your Windows is up-to-date with the latest updates and patches.If not, please install this updates.
2.Try to manually remove VS from your machine.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
%programdata%\Microsoft\visualstudio\packages
%Temp%
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\1X.0_XXXXXXXX


Delete the setup registry key, which was set when you installed VS for the first time:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Setup
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Setup
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Setup
(Note: For security reasons, please back up your registry before modifying.)

3.Please read the following docs and make sure your computer meets the system requirements.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/system-requirements
After doing these, please download fresh version from VS download page and reinstall. If the issue persists, i suggest you to collect installation logs and check or share error messages to figure out what causes the black screen.
1 download Microsoft Visual Studio and .NET Framework log collection tool
https://aka.ms/vscollect
2 run Collect.exe in  an administrative command prompt
The tool generates a vslogs.zip file in your %TEMP% folder, typically at C:\Users\YourName\AppData\Local\Temp\vslogs.zip.
For more information, please refer to:Troubleshoot installation or upgrades - Visual Studio (Windows) | Microsoft Learn
